# Inconsistent accessibility error: field less accessible than field

Tags: c#, .net, events, delegates

I've tried to solve this problem that I have but I really don't know what else to do. I get this error:
`Inconsistent accessibility: field type 'ChatClient.Configurator.IPChangeHandler' is less accessible than field 'ChatClient.Configurator.IPChange'`

and this is part of the code:

```
namespace ChatClient
{
    public partial class Configurator : Form
    {
        public delegate void IPChangeHandler(object sender, IPAddressInfoEventArgs e);
        public event IPChangeHandler IPChange;
        // ...
    }
}
```

making delegate and class public did not worked out.
Thank you!

Comment: The error message says that your IPChangeHandler delegate is not in fact *public*.  You'll get another error message if you also forgot to make IPAddressInfoEventArgs public.  Which is probably the remaining problem, you didn't document the error message properly.

Answer (score 1):

Check accessible level of IPAddressInfoEventArgs class.

It must be **public** since the event `IPChange` is public too.

Comment: Thank you!  IPAddressInfoEventArgs class wasn't public. Now it's working.

Answer (score 0):

Please Go to Solution Part ..& Open the IPAddressInfoEventArgs.cs file ....

Update in that File....

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace ChatClient
{
    public class IPAddressInfoEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
       private string _ipAddress;
       public IPAddressInfoEventArgs(string ipAddress)
        {
            this._ipAddress = ipAddress;
        }

        public string IPAddress
        {
            get { return this._ipAddress; }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: **this** is Working I **Tried** It